# Is it possible to export cpu and memory usage from firebase test lab results?

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am using firebase google service as a way of testing an application with different setting each time for cpu and memory consumption. I would like though to download the dataset used to make the graphs available in the test lab of firebase.
The graphs mentioned are these shown here = [firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f0jK.png)
Please keep in mind that these data are NOT available in the test results bucket.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (May 2019) I'm not aware of any existing client that would download this data for you.

The data is available though through the [Tool Results API](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/toolresults/v1beta3/), specifically the `toolresults.projects.histories.executions.steps.perfSampleSeries` endpoint.

The`list` method gives you the metadata for all available graphs. This is where you would get the series ids.

The `samples.list` method gives you the data points for a series.

Client libraries for [Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/toolresults/v1beta3) and [Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/toolresults/v1beta3) are provided by Google, but no specific samples for **Tool Results** are provided. There are some general examples how to do authentication, ... with these client libraries.

Comment: any information on how to use this API? Checked the documents but they seem overly complicated for just to download a set of data

Comment: Added links to the client libraries developer sites provided by Google, which should get you started.